# How change the memory frequency in raspberry pi 4

Tags: memory, raspberry-pi, frequency, raspberry-pi4

How to change the frequency of memory in raspberry pi 4 in a similar way to how we change the CPU frequency. so scientific articles mention that we can do that from the BIOS but i did not find any way to do that.

Comment: Frequency of memory? What do you mean by that, can you please elaborate?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about programming and probably belongs on raspberrypi.stackexchange.com